# TinyOS , Could not receive the packet after restarting the mote

Tags: tinyos, nesc

pseudocode;

1. 1-boot (red led)
2. broadcast the packet,after send done(green light)
3. receive the packet, decode the packet and set led accordingly as (set blue)
4. broadcast the packet after coding, send done (set led green)
5. receive packet, decode it and set led accordingly as (set 7 (red+green+blue))

---

after this stage mote 1 will bet LED.set(7) and mote 2 will be LED.set(2) [mote 1 has started the transmission] ,till there it works very fine. but when i restart mote 1 it works till 2 steps of pseudocode and mote 2 could not able to receive the packet)

```
 implementation{
 bool busy = FALSE;
 message_t pkt;
 message_t i_pkt;
 event void Boot.booted() {

    call Leds.set(1);
    call AMControl.start();
    printf("Booted %d\n",1);
    call CC2420Packet.setPower(&pkt, 20);
    call CC2420Packet.setPower(&i_pkt, 2);
 }

 event void Timer0.fired() {

    if (!busy) {
       FindRoute_t *btrpkt = (FindRoute_t*)(call Packet.getPayload(&pkt, sizeof (FindRoute_t)));

       btrpkt->counter = 4;
       if (call firstsender.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &pkt, sizeof(FindRoute_t)) == SUCCESS) {
       busy = TRUE;
       }
    }

 }


 event void AMControl.startDone(error_t err) {
    if (err == SUCCESS) {
       call Timer0.startOneShot(250);
    }
    else {
       call AMControl.start();
    }
 }

 event void AMControl.stopDone(error_t err) {
 } 

 event void firstsender.sendDone(message_t *msg, error_t error) {
   if (&pkt == msg) {
      call Leds.set(2);
      busy = FALSE;
    }
 }

 event message_t* firstreceiver.receive(message_t* msg, void* payload, uint8_t len) {
    if (len == sizeof(FindRoute_t)) {
       FindRoute_t* btrpkt = (FindRoute_t*)payload;
       call Leds.set(btrpkt->counter);

       call Timer1.startOneShot(3000);
    }
    return msg;
 }


  event void Timer1.fired(){

     if (!busy) {
       FindRoute_t *btrpkt = (FindRoute_t*)(call Packet.getPayload(&i_pkt, sizeof (FindRoute_t)));

       btrpkt->counter = 7;
       if (call nextsender.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &i_pkt, sizeof(FindRoute_t)) == SUCCESS) {
       busy = TRUE;
       }
    }
  }
  event void nextsender.sendDone(message_t *msg, error_t error) {
   if (&i_pkt == msg) {
      call Leds.set(2);
      busy = FALSE;
    }
 }

   event message_t* nextreceiver.receive(message_t* msg, void* payload, uint8_t len) {
    if (len == sizeof(FindRoute_t)) {
       FindRoute_t* btrpkt = (FindRoute_t*)payload;
       call Leds.set(btrpkt->counter);
    }
    return msg;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two receivers. Are they wired to two different receiving modules? If not, a received packet will trigger both of their receive event, which may cause some problem.